# Can't install any OS, hdd errors

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I am trying to install any OS on a netbook (Samsung n150), I tried win xp, which hangs trying to boot saying something like `(hd0,0)`. I tried win 7, which loads the installer setup but when it reaches the point where you create partitions it shows some incompatible hardware error. I tried several linux distros (including system tools like clonezilla and gparted). and they all start booting  until they show something like this:

```
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x0
ata1.00: BMDMA stat 0x25
ata1.00: failed command: READ DMA
ata1.00: status: { DRDY ERR }
ata1.00: error: { ABRT }
```

And they keep repeating that forever.

Is there something I could try to recover this computer? Because since I wasn't even able to run linux live cds I can't even test the disk for errors and such. Or should I assume the hdd is dead and can't be recovered?

Comment: If you can't boot off a CD it might not be the HDD that's the problem. Can you pull the Drive and install it in a different machine to see if it boots there? If you can't boot from either HDD or CD you should pull your RAM and have it tested. Just had another thought - if your machine is 32 bit architecture and the OS is 64, you won't be able to load. But my guess is that it's related to your RAM.

Comment: @BenPlont I don't have any machine compatible with this type of hdd (it's a netbook). I boot from USB since this netbook doesn't have a cd/dvd, but everything I try to boot fail at some point, always seems hdd related like the error I posted.

Comment: the HDD shouldn't be used at all during the process of booting from USB (unless you're installing the OS).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that this is the hard drive hardware failure and you will need to change your drive to a new one.

Nevertheless, open your netboot, diconnect this drive and then boot your machine from USB drive. Most Linux installation images have "Live CD" mode, it is "Try" , not "Install" menu at beginning. Select "Try" and have your test that machine works itself without your problematical hard drive. I think it will, because most likely it is the hard drive fault/failure.

Comment: Yep, can boot live cds without problems with the hdd disconnected. I guess someone shook or dropped the netbook while the hdd was spinning, cause it looks pretty beaten up, the plastic case is all cracked and things like that.

Comment: If you are looking for a further usage of this machine and increasing of its speed then SSD drive is better to purchase rather than hdd again.